# Google DFP Responsive Ads - only 320x50px Ad Show

Tags: javascript, google-dfp

Google DFP generate own Responsive Ads look like:

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var googletag = googletag || {};
  googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
  (function() {
    var gads = document.createElement('script');
    gads.async = true;
    gads.type = 'text/javascript';
    var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
    gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
      '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
    var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
  })();
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    googletag.defineSlot('/XXXXXXX/deutung-sidebar', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-XXXXXXXXXXXX-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.defineSlot('/XXXXXXX/deutung-header', [[728, 90], [320, 50]], 'div-gpt-ad-XXXXXXXXXXXX-1').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.enableServices();
  });
</script>
```

on Content:

```html
<div id='div-gpt-ad-XXXXXXXXX-1'>
<script type='text/javascript'>
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-XXXXXXXX-1'); });
</script>
</div>
```

This works fine but sometimes it dosent show 728 Ads (on a FullHD Display), after Reload the Page it works (50% of impression with wrong adsize). What could i do?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't done a proper implementation of responsive ads.  For example, you've never defined the viewport size.  Refer to the example here:
https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/4578089